# How to show that language L is NOT context-free?

Tags: context-free, closure-properties

**True or false**: *To show that a language L is not context-free, one can alternatively show that the union between L and a known context-free language is not context-free.*

I know that you can prove closure under context-free languages using union, but does the above work, too? Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes, you can use it

Comment: I am not sure which student of mine you are but please just do the quiz for CSE355 to the best of *your* ability.

Comment: Try to think of some CS languages, a couple of CF ones and check their unions. See if you get an idea for a proof. *Show how far you got*, where you see yourself stuck.

Comment: BTW Is there a known case in which proving that the union with a CF language is not CF helps or makes it easier to prove that the original language is not CF? From a logical point of view it seems impossible